# Error in binding resource string with a view in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to bind a static string defined in the Resources.resx called title. When I run the application I get the following error below.

Upon investigating the error on this site, I found that the generated Resources class is marked internal and WPF is trying to resolve the resource from another assembly, so it won't succeed until your resources are marked as public. The same, I have a single project which contains my views and resources defined.

I don’t need any friend assembly. I believe the internal class can be accessed within the same assembly. I found [a similar post by a fellow user](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13830/Extended-Strongly-Typed-Resource-Generator) in which he suggested to use ResXFileCodeGenerator. What is your say on this?

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
HResult=-2146233087
Message='Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '11' and line position '9'.
Source=PresentationFramework
LineNumber=11
LinePosition=9
StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at TestApp.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in ~\TestApp\TestApp\MainWindow.xaml:line 1
   at TestApp.MainWindow..ctor() in ~\TestApp\TestApp\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 28
InnerException: System.ArgumentException
   HResult=-2147024809
   Message='TestApp.Properties.Resources.Firstname' StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property.
   Source=System.Xaml
   StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: When you get an error like this, you can ignore this message... it is basically a wrapper for an inner `Exception`. We need to know what the inner `Exception`, or even the inner, inner `Exception` message says. You can find out by clicking on the `View details` link on the popup `Exception` notification window in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is what the inner exception says. fyi the above exception is copied from inner exception 'TestApp.Properties.Resources.Firstname' StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property.

Comment: moreover i am trying to bind title of the window object from resource string

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the inner `Exception`... I just saw the very common `System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException` and ignored the rest. Please show us how you have tried to access your resource string.

Comment: Oh yes, it does seem that you need to use the `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` generator. Have you tried right clicking in the resource file in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and selecting the `Properties` option and then setting the `Custom Tool` property to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`? You can also set the `Access Modifier` property to `Public` in the resources designer window in Visual Studio.

Comment: for all the properties or just the class?

Comment: For the Resx file. Find it in the Solution Explorer, open the properties window for it and change the `Custom Tool` setting there.

Comment: thanks it worked by changing all the properties and class modifiers to public :) cheers

Answer (score 42):

It seems that you need to use the `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` generator.

Try right clicking on the resource file in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer and selecting the `Properties` option and then setting the `Custom Tool` property to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. You can also set the `Access Modifier` property to `Public` in the resources designer window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Note: I had to restart Visual studio after setting Modifiers to public.